# R Splitting a column by chunks and regrouping

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a data.frame

```
> blah
  Col1 Val1 Col2 Val2
1    A    1    B   10
2    A    2    B   20
3    A    3    B   30

structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    Val1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Col2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "B", class = "factor"), 
    Val2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("10", "20", "30"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("COl1", 
"Val1", "Col2", "Val2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

where col1 and col2 are repeated id columns.

I want to split the dataframe by the Column Name and recombine them so that the final result looks like.

```
> blah
   Col  Val
1    A    1
2    A    2
3    A    3
4    B   10
5    B   20
6    B   30
```

I've been trying using melt and reshape but haven't had much luck.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from using `rbind(blah[,c('Col1','Val1')],blah[,c('Col2','Val2')])` ? It doesn't seem like you want to go from wide to long, you just have multiple columns that should be under the same header

Comment: You can do this with reshape - `reshape(blah, sep="", direction="long", varying=names(blah))`

Comment: @user20650 - nope, the `sep=""` guesses the groups based on whatever precedes the numbers.

Comment: ugh...ok thanks thelatemail